# Prelude not loading Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to use QuickCheck to test some properties of some functions, after I 'Install' QuickCheck and try to use it I got an error saying that module prelude could not be loaded.

Exact error message:

```
Could not load module ‘Prelude’
It is a member of the hidden package ‘base-4.18.0.0’.
You can run ‘:set -package base’ to expose it.
(Note: this unloads all the modules in the current scope.)
```

I tried to go back to a previous git commit but the error remains there. How can I solve this?

I have GHC version 9.6.2 base-4.18.0.0

Comment: What command do you run that causes that message to appear?

Comment: I am doing import Prelude hiding (maximum, foldr) . And some other imports, but all of them have the error saying 'Could not load module'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [Cabal issue #8894](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/8894). You can work around it by either downgrading to Cabal 3.8 and just ignoring the warning about an unknown/unsupported GHC version or doing `cabal install --lib base`.

Comment: I did cabal install --lib base and it gave me an 'up to date', is that ok?

Comment: @diegog I think that's fine. See if it fixed the problem.

Comment: This is not necessarily issue 8894. People (diegog or others) can experience this by omitting `base` from the `build-depends` field of their project's `.cabal` file.

Comment: Thank you, prelude error is not showing anymore, I guess it worked. I am getting an error in importing Generic.Random.Generic, which is for using QuickCheck, I guess it is a different problem